# Limit of sequence with floor function problem

Tags: calculus, limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have to evaluate limit of sequence

> $ \lim_{n \rightarrow\infty } \frac{n \sqrt{n} \sqrt[n]{(n+1)^{n}+n^{n+1}}}{[\sqrt n]+[2 \sqrt n]+...+[n\sqrt n]} $.

"[...]" here denotes floor function. What troubles me here the most is the floor function in it, I am not sure what to do with it.

Comment: Use the fact that $x - 1 < \lfloor x \rfloor \le x$, to get upper and lower bounds on the ratio.

Comment: Okay, I am going to try to compute it now, I would be using central limit theorem for it?

Comment: The central limit theorem I know is about probability, so that may not be very relevant here.

Comment: I am sorry I thought that the inequality with limits that is in answer below is called central limit theorem.

Comment: Ah now I understand what you mean. Cool, glad you understood and got the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Noting that $x-1 \lt \lfloor x \rfloor \le x$, we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}(k\sqrt{n}-1) \lt \sum_{k=1}^{n}\lfloor k\sqrt{n}\rfloor \le \sum_{k=1}^{n}k\sqrt{n},$$
that is,
$$\frac{n(n+1)\sqrt{n}}{2}-n \lt \sum_{k=1}^{n}\lfloor k\sqrt{n}\rfloor \le \frac{n(n+1)\sqrt{n}}{2}.$$
Plug it into the limit, we get
$$\frac{2(n^{n+1}+(n+1)^n)^{1/n}}{n+1} \le f(n) \lt \frac{2(n^{n+1}+(n+1)^n)^{1/n}}{n+1-2/\sqrt{n}}.$$

Since the limit of the functions on the left and right are equal, we need only to compute the one on left hand side.

\begin{align}
&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2(n^{n+1}+(n+1)^n)^{1/n}}{n+1} \\
=&2\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+n(\frac{n}{n+1})^n)^{1/n} \\
=&2\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+n(1-\frac{1}{n+1})^n)^{1/n} \\
=&2\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{n}{e})^{1/n} \\
=&2
\end{align}

Therefore, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=2$.

Comment: Thank you for answering, it took me a while to understand, but now I get it.

Comment: @cryogenic: You're welcome:) BTW, that theorem is called the squeeze theorem.