# "Partial" evaluation of limit

Tags: calculus, limits

I have a question regarding to limits. I am going to refer to answer in this question [Limit of sequence with floor function problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633718/limit-of-sequence-with-floor-function-problem). There is a limit that is computed this way:
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2(n^{n+1}+(n+1)^n)^{1/n}}{n+1} \\
=&2\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+n(\frac{n}{n+1})^n)^{1/n} \\
=&2\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+n(1-\frac{1}{n+1})^n)^{1/n} \\
=&2\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{n}{e})^{1/n} \\
=&2
\end{align}

It occurred to me later, but there is one thing that troubles me. We were told by professors not to "partially evaluate limits".I am not sure whether the term is correctly used. In cases like:
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}\not=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(1+\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n})^{n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(1+0)^{n}=1
\end{align}
Is that same case as with:

> $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(1-\frac{1}{n+1})^n=\frac{1}{e}$

But the solution is in fact correct. So what is the difference? Under what condition can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have a core idea like this, there's often an an easy fix to turn it into an obviously correct argument.

In this case, you can take the 0-th order approximation to the "inner" limit and know that

$$2\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+n (\frac{1}{e} - \epsilon))^{1/n} 
\leq 2\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+n(1-\frac{1}{n+1})^n)^{1/n} 
\leq 2\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+n (\frac{1}{e} + \epsilon))^{1/n}  $$

is true for for every small positive number $\epsilon$.

Comment: could you explain me what is the "0-th order approximation"?

Comment: Here, it's a fancy way of saying that I'm approximating a sequence with its limit.

Comment: So it has nothing to do with Taylor polynomial?(which I haven't learned to use yet). Then what you propose is that I try to evaluate "inner" limit to find upper/lower bound for squeeze theorem?

Comment: Yes, squeeze theorem is my plan. The method of exhaustion (e.g. if $-\epsilon < x < \epsilon$ for every positive $\epsilon$, then $x=0$) often needs to be used in arguments like this too, but it's unnecessary here. I would indeed use the phrase "$n$-th order approximation" if I replaced a function with its $n$-th degree Taylor polynomial. There are a few other scenarios I would use it as well. I didn't elaborate since it's a little awkward to describe here.

Comment: What I needed to know is that I don't need Taylor's polynomial as we haven't studied and proved it my class so I neither know it nor can I use it. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is the following. $n$ is your power, and is going to infinity. So you cannot bring the $\lim$ inside the parenthesis since you have to evaluate to a power that goes to infinity. If you had a constant (and finite) power (for example $m$) like in
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left( 1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^m
$$
then it would be ok to bring the limit inside and you would, indeed, get $1$. 
The rule usually is that if you have a finite number of functions the limit of the product (if the functions are real valued and all has limits) is the product of the limits. But here you have asyntontically infinite number of functions, this is why is not working.

You could do a series expansion considering $n$ a real variable (and not anymore restricted to integers) around $\infty$. In this case you would get $2(1+1/n(-\log(1/n)-1)+O(1/n^2))$. Then the limit becomes much easier...

Comment: thank you for your answer, I do understand why it is not working, but my question was why it is working in the second case, where the whole expression is to the power 1/n,which is increasing, not constant.

Comment: But in your second expression you are not bringing the limit inside the function... Or am I missing something?

Comment: it was part of the sequence from the beginning 
$2\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+n(1-\frac{1}{n+1})^n)^{1/n}$

Comment: Yeah but again, the limit remains outside the power of $1/n$. You are bringing $n+1$ inside, but not the limit.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your comment, how else did we get from $2\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+n(1-\frac{1}{n+1})^n)^{1/n}$ this $2\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{n}{e})^{1/n}$. By not computing limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(1-\frac{1}{n+1})^n=\frac{1}{e}$

Comment: You are right. Sorry, I missed the passage. I think that the two limits are the same is not related. You cannot do the passage letting $e$ appear like this... Let me think if I can calculate the limit in a different way...